# Implement handleRedirectPromise of msal-angular

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

When user accessed our web app through direct URL for example `'localhost.com/profile/myaccount'` user is being navigated to microsoft login after successful authentication being redirected to `'localhost.com'` instead of requested URL i.e `'localhost.com/profile/myaccount'`.
when I check internet found this source [how-does-the-handleredirectpromise-function-work](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/FAQ.md#i-dont-understand-the-redirect-flow-how-does-the-handleredirectpromise-function-work). Iam not sure how to implement this